# android app index integration

Tags: android

Am new to android app indexing concept, here am facing some trouble to integrate app index, at present am using eclipse for development. i have some doubts in manifest file please see the code below

```
 <data android:scheme="http"
  android:host="recipe-app.com"
  android:pathPrefix="/recipe" />
```

here what is the pathprefix?? what should i give in that place?? and what is use of it ?? if am not using pathprefix, then is an app working perfectly ?? also i have done code inside of my MainActivity

```
    mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(HomePageActivity.this).addApi(
            AppIndex.APP_INDEX_API).build();
```

in onStart() i have connect with google using mApiClient.connect(). but still am not able to see in my chrome browser, should i release a beta version in play store ?? what i want to do to work perfect way ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The data element in intent filters is used to match parts of a URI and decide which Activity should be opened. In your example, the intent filter containing that data element, would only match URIs beginning with http://recipe-app.com/recipe

If you want your activity to match any URL in your domain, you need to remove the pathPrefix attribute completely:

```
<data android:scheme="http"
android:host="recipe-app.com" />
```

You can add multiple data elements to your app's intent filters to match different schema, domains, subdomains or pathPrefix combinations as needed to handle all your website URLs.

In order for Google to start indexing your app and show it in search results, you must verify your website ownership in Google Webmaster Tools, and link it to your Android app in Google Play Developer Console.